# Assigning multiple IPs to the same machine with one interface

Tags: ip, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, bridge, iproute2

I have a server with a single physical interface `eth0`. I intend on running VMs on this server. To that end I have an IPv4 block which is routed to said server. What I'm trying to achieve is to spin-up VMs into a local subnet `10.0.0.0/8` and then 1-to-1 NAT an external IP to an internal IP, thus effectively providing those VMs with external IPs and Internet access.

The 1-to-1 NAT is no problem, but I'm having issues with getting the hypervisor to accept and process traffic for all the external IPs (even without any form of NAT). I'm testing everything out with a single /30 net, with following IPs

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.0/30
xxx.xxx.xxx.1/30
xxx.xxx.xxx.2/30
xxx.xxx.xxx.3/30
```

Assume eth0 has ip `yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy`. IPv4 packet forwarding is enabled.

I can get my hypervisors (or VMs) to respond to the lowest address in the block, all the other addresses are being ignored, it seems.

I tried adding all the IPs as a an alias to eth0:

```
ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.0/30 dev eth0 label eth0:1
ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.1/30 dev eth0 label eth0:1
ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.2/30 dev eth0 label eth0:1
ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.3/30 dev eth0 label eth0:1
```

I also tried using /32 instead of /30, and to use differing labels, and a combination of all of the above. That didn't work. Next up, I decided to create a bridge which has the entire subnet attached to it.

```
br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether ea:5a:59:06:8a:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.0/30 brd 5.39.22.163 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.1/30 brd 5.39.22.163 scope global secondary br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.2/30 brd 5.39.22.163 scope global secondary br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.3/30 brd 5.39.22.163 scope global secondary br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Again, no success. I then created a bridge, but without attaching an IP to it. I simply added a route to the subnet on that bridge. I don't need my hypervisor to actually respond to the traffic, I just need it to accept it so iptables processes it and applies the NAT.

```
ip route add xxx.xxx.xxx.0/30 dev br0
```

This also wasn't a success.

In all the cases I tried, the hypervisor (or the VM, if I enabled the 1-to-1 NAT) would be able to respond to traffic for xxx.xxx.xxx.0, any of the other IPs in the block are ignored.

Comment: Those `ip addr add` commands look OK. What didn't work?

Comment: @MarkWagner The last sentence says it all: "[...] the hypervisor [...] would be able to respond to traffic for xxx.xxx.xxx.0, any of the other IPs in the block are ignored." That's the basic issue here: no matter what I try, I can only get traffic working on the xxx.xxx.xxx.0 address, not on any of the other IPs in the IP block.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're doing due to obfuscation but a /30 is only going to have 2 valid host addresses. E.g., 192.168.0.0/30 has 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2.

Comment: I know, but you need to view it as a bunch of IPs for which traffic is routed to my network so .0 - .3 are all valid IPs. I used this block on a different server as well and that worked fine. I'm using a different ditro on the new server, though. I have also started a support ticket with the hosting company. I'm hoping this is just a routing issue at their end.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem turned out to be a routing issue at the datacenter. Not all traffic was routed to my server correctly.

My final setup looks like this:

```
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC ADDRESS> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet <hypervisor IP/netmask> brd <broadcast addr> scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: local_net: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether fe:00:05:27:16:a0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.1/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global local_net
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So I only assign the hypervisor's IP to the physical interface. Then I create a local bridge. That bridge is has a DHCP server listeneing on it and giving static leases to pre-defined MAC addresses of the VM, so each VM receives the same local IP every time it boots.

Then, to get the 1-to-1 NAT going, I simply add rules like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <public VM IP>/32 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination <local VM IP>
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s <local VM IP>/32 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source <public VM IP>
```

This will translate all traffic arriving on `eth0` for one of the VM's IPs to the VM, and all traffic coming from the VM  to public IP.

Answer (score 0):

In each subnet, the first address is for the network, and the last is usually for broadcast. so xxx.xxx.xxx.0 and xxx.xxx.xxx.3 wont work for a /30 class network, and all IP addresses on a /32 network are network addresses. network addresses are used for routing, and cannot be assigned to a device

If you want to use /30 class networks, you can use xxx.xxx.xxx.1 and xxx.xxx.xxx.2 on one network segment (the xxx.xxx.xxx.0 network) and xxx.xxx.xxx.5 and xxx.xxx.xxx.6 on another network segment (xxx.xxx.xxx.4 network)

Perhaps try a different /24 class network.

Also, it looks like your trying to assign all IP addresses to eth0:1 , try using eth0:2, eth0:3 and eth0:4

Another command to try is "ifconfig eth0 add x.x.x.1 netmask 255.255.255.0", or with "netmask 255.255.255.252" for a /32 class network. this command will automatically assign the subinterface numbers for you, starting with eth0:0, using eth0:1 next.

Also, im not sure if the networks can be referred to as being "/30 class" or "/24 class". I'm not sure what the proper term is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your explanation of subnets is correct, and I misused the word. I should've simply used "IP block" instead of "subnet", as the datacenter provides me with a block of IP addresses for which all traffic is routed to my server. As mentioned in the question, I had already tried multiple different labels, and many other things. This turned out to be the datacenter's fault. Check my own answer for more details on the actual working configuration.

Answer (score 0):

With IPv4, the lowest address on a network, with two exceptions, is the network address, and it is unusable for assignment to a host.

If you have a `/32`, that is a single host address which must be routed. Such an address is normally used as a router loopback address.

If you have a `/31`, that is a network used for point-to-point links since it only has two usable addresses. Originally, `/31` networks were unusable, but [RFC 3021, Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021) changed that.

To use four addresses in the same network, the longest mask you can have is `/29`, which gives you six usable addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your explanation of subnets is correct, and I misused the word. I should've simply used "IP block" instead of "subnet", as the datacenter provides me with a block of IP addresses for which all traffic is routed to my server. Check my own answer for more details on the actual working configuration.